# How can I best restrict String.compareTo() results to -1, 0, and 1?

Tags: java

I realize that the results for string1.compareTo(string2) will be a number -1 or below if string2 comes before string1 alphabetically, and a number 1 or above if different the other direction. I need to return only -1, 0, or 1.

I can code it in a seemingly clunky way, but I feel like there must be a more efficient/elegant way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

```
String s1 = "aardvark";
String s2 = "zebra";
int c = s1.compareTo(s2); // -25
if (c > 0) {
   c = 1;
} else if (c < 0) {
   c = -1;
}
```

Is there some sort of mathematical operation that will change all positive integers to 1 and all negative integers to -1?

---

EDIT: I have to say, I'm gratified just to have asked a question that wasn't downvoted and deleted, but the prompt and intelligent responses are wonderful. Here are the answers I've tested so far. I wanted to share my results with those who come later.

My test code: (runs each solution about 2600 times at different values)

```
String s1 = "";
String s2 = "m";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   for (char j = 'a'; j < 'z'; j++) {
      s2 = ("" + j);
      solution1(s1.compareTo(s2));
   }
}
```

My original code: ~1.5ms

```
if (c > 0) {
   c = 1;
} else if (c < 0) {
   c = -1;
}
```

Solution 1: ~4ms

```
c = (int) Math.signum(c);
```

Solution 2: ~2ms

```
c = c > 0 ? 1 : c < 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

Solution 3: ~2ms

```
c = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, c));
```

Solution 4: ~2ms

```
c = Integer.compare(c, 0);
```

I like them all better than my original, so thank you all collectively. Solution 4 gets the check mark due to speed and readability, so thank you especially.

Comment: There is `Math.signum` but it only takes a `float` or `double`; using it and casting your `int` and the result will not be more efficient than what you're already doing.

Comment: Well there's no shorter way doing that, while using the implement comparable . use might be need to override your String class and point what what exactly is bigger string ? Is it length ? Is is alphabet order ? Using the implement comparable you will receive value smaller/bigger than zero .

Comment: @Barak Kedem: String is a final class. good luck trying to override it

Comment: @RandomRaccoon: this is actually not possible, since you can't change the String class. you can however write your own utility class with methods to 'accomplish' this, but you can't change the actual compareTo method or it's output (except possibly locally)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very simple:

```
return Integer.compare(s1.compareTo(s2), 0);
```

Comment: I checked this to make sure it works, and it does. Despite the documentation saying only that it gives a "positive number" or "negative number" as output, it seems to always be -1, 0, or 1. Any catch with this method that would cause an unexpected result?

Comment: No, if you check its source code, it just says `return left < right? -1 : left > right? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator would be more compact :

```
c = c>0?1:c<0?-1:0;
```

Math.signum can also be used, but will require a cast to int :

```
c = (int)Math.signum(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Math.signum()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum(double)) provides what you ask for:

> Returns the signum function of the argument; zero if the argument is zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument is less than zero.

Comment: But it takes a `float` or `double` - casting the `int`, to `float` or `double`, and the result of `signum` back to `int`, will not make it more efficient.

Comment: It's elegant, what you are asking for. Is it efficient? So so.

Comment: But not efficient. If you look at the source code of `Math.signum` in the JDK, you'll see that it's more complicated than what randomraccoon is already doing.

Answer (score 2):

You could clamp the value range using min and max. That is a useful method sometimes, so you could use it as a utility method:

```
String s1 = "aardvark";
String s2 = "zebra";
int c = s1.compareTo(s2); // -25
return clamp(c, -1, 1);
```

With

```
int clamp(int value, int min, int max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
}
```

More elegant? I would say so. More efficient? Probably not.